# What does normalizing the gradient magnitude signify?

Tags: computer-vision

```
  Normalized Gradient = [Gradient(x,y) - Mean_Gradient(5*5 window)]/ Deviation(5*5 Window)
```

What does Normalized gradient signify here ?

Answer (score 0):

Practically it does not make much sense because gradient is sparse in an image, however if the image is of some texture which has a certain gradient prevalent throughout the image (sub-image), then such a normalization would help to get the relative gradient with respect to the gradient in the surroundings.